# Somar um valor em um campo com rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Olá! Na minha tabela usuários tenho um campo de `downloads`.
Gostaria que quando o usuário entrasse na pagina eu somasse +1 nesse campo do usuário.

Qual a melhor maneira de fazer isso? Preciso realmente fazer 2 querys? pegar o valor atual e depois somar outro, ou existe um jeito de simplesmente somar um valor àquele valor já existente?

Comment: Como você fez a parte de autenticação com o usuário? Com o [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)? Por que nesse caso ele só carrega o objeto do Usuário uma vez de depois mantêm em *cache*.

Comment: sim, com o devise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você prestar atenção nos *logs*, verá que o [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) só faz a busca pelo usuário (`SELECT ... FROM usuarios ...`) uma única vez na requisição, e depois retorna do *cache* se requisitado.

Assim não haverá qualquer problema em usar:

```
current_usuario.downloads + 1
```

para atualizar. Tente uma das abordagens, se não funcionar me avise:

```
current_usuario.downloads = current_usuario.downloads + 1
current_usuario.save

# ou
Usuario.update(current_usuario.id, downloads: (current_usuario.downloads + 1))
```

Comment: Olá. Não funcionou. ele não faz o update. Não da nenhum erro e no prompt tbm nao mostra nenhuma query referente...

Comment: @IgorMartins Atualizei, me diga se depois funcionou.

Comment: Useri o primeiro método, funcionou!!! obrigado